# Retrofit / Dagger - Android : Fatal Exception: API declarations must be interfaces

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger-2

I'm very new to Retrofit and Dagger I'm getting a fatal exception stating: *API declarations must be interfaces.* being thrown in the following example:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_network);
    findViewById(R.id.test_network_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(NetworkViewModel.class);
```

**ViewModelProviderFactory.java:**

```
public class ViewModelProviderFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

private static final String TAG = "ViewModelProviderFactor";

private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;


@Inject
public ViewModelProviderFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
    this.creators = creators;
}

@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
    Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
    if (creator == null) { 


        for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {


            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                creator = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    if (creator == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
    }


    try {
        return (T) creator.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

**NetworkModule.java:**

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {


@Singleton
@Provides
static StudioDataApi provideNetworkApi(Retrofit retrofit) {

    return retrofit.create(StudioDataApi.class);
}
}
```

**Full Logcat Error:**
https://pastebin.com/V0hqrEc6

P.S.

Any suggestions / tips / ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Although, I can't see where do you initialize the `RetroFit` or the callbacks of it but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592549/8244632).

Comment: I think the error might be in `StudioDataApi`, could you please post the definition of this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be that your `StudioDataApi` is not an interface. When you call `create` in retrofit it validates your api. [Here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/63cf3e66c4b661170a34a396e9be8a2a01c0e57f/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java#L140) you can see a call to `validateServiceInterface` which in turn will throw the mentioned exception [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/63cf3e66c4b661170a34a396e9be8a2a01c0e57f/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java#L167). If you check the `if` statement above, it's checking if the api you're creating is an interface.

**Why does retrofit require such a thing?**

Internally retrofit uses the [Proxy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to create your services. Basically, when you call `create` it returns a proxy for your service/api. This allows you to treat your service the way you want and behind the scenes when you call your service methods, it'll make sure to call the api for you.

This alone is not enough to throw the mentioned exception, however, retrofit doesn't reinvent the wheel and uses java's implementation of the proxy pattern. When calling `create` it actually calls [`Proxy.newProxyInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) which requires your service to be an interface.